# JTree model is wierdly updated after deleting some nodes

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree

I'm stuck with standard `JTree` default model. Here is the point.

I created some kind of XML editor, I have a `JTree` component and a `JTextPane` component. I can delete nodes in `JTree` by using my GUI, code here:

```
DefaultTreeModel model = MyGUI.treemodel;    // this is a model of my jtree
for (int i=0; i<arrayCheckboxes.size(); i++) {    // I am using checkboxes for selecting nodes to delete
    if (arrayCheckboxes.get(i).isSelected()) {
        model.removeNodeFromParent((MutableTreeNode) thisnode.getChildAt(i+2));    // first two childs should be kept
    }
}
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(MyGUI.tree);  // refreshing UI
```

So, everything is OK, I can see in the `JTree` that nodes were deleted.

After that stuff I am exporting my new `JTree` to XML file, code here:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ConvertToXML {

    public static void convert() {

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("JOB");

            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // Get tree root...
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) MyGUI.treemodel.getRoot();
            System.out.println("model in convert: " + MyGUI.treemodel);
            Node node = (Node) root.getUserObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < node.getAttributes().getLength() - 1; i++) {
                rootElement.setAttribute(node.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeName(), node.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue());
            }

            parseTreeNode(node.getChildNodes(), rootElement);

            // Save the document to disk...

            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            jFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Укажите файл для сохранения");
            int userSelection = jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(MyGUI.frame);
            File fileToSave = null;
            if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileToSave = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println("Сохранить как: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());

            }


            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            //StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("TreeModel.xml"));
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(fileToSave);
            tf.transform(domSource, sr);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static void parseTreeNode(NodeList nodeList, Node doc) {
        String nameNode;
        for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {
            Element parentElement = null;
            Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

            if ((tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)) {
                nameNode = tempNode.getNodeName();
                parentElement = doc.getOwnerDocument().createElement(nameNode);
                doc.appendChild(parentElement);
                for (int i = 0; i < tempNode.getAttributes().getLength(); i++) {
                    parentElement.setAttribute(tempNode.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeName(), tempNode.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue());
                }
            }
            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                parseTreeNode(tempNode.getChildNodes(), parentElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And what I got? I haven't any changes in my new XML file as to compare to original, it seems that I don't delete anything in my model. But why can it be happen?
Please help me, I'm totally stuck with this bug.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Seems problem in next: you store in `TreeNode` loaded from old xml `Node`  as `userObject`. And then here `parseTreeNode(node.getChildNodes(), rootElement);` you iterate children of old `Node`, but seems you need to iterate through `DefaultMutableTreeNode root` children.

Comment: alex2410, thank you! Now it's all fine!